# What is the best way to get started in GUI C++ programming?

Tags: c++, user-interface

So, I learned C++ (fundamentals) and I want to write software, however I have stumbled upon a problem where I don't know where to get started. It seems like learning C++ was the easiest part by far when it comes to understanding the libraries for the GUI construction the concept I yet don't fully comprehend. I searched a lot and couldn't even decide been a new guy on MFC, Win32 or Qt.

Qt C++ GUI seems like a fun and easy to use software with the definitions of classes available right there quickly.

With Visual's MFC I am seeing a lot of code upfront on the pre made project file and a lot of description of classes, however getting definitions is a bit slower as I have to go to the internet.

Win32 is apparently written in C and is not updated much?

A lot of people recommend Java and C# as well, but I am not interested in learning a new language when I don't have C++ set in stone and practiced with enough yet.

Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: I'd still advise C# and WinForms. Adapting to C# from C++ is trivial. The reason C# and WinForms is suggested is because it allow you to generate boilerplate code via a visual drag-and-drop editor for the GUI while you wire up the logic using C#.

Comment: @Sion Sheevok: But C# and WinForms is a limitation (there is more than Win32).

Comment: @Sion Sheevok: or C# and WPF!

Comment: @Sion Sheevok. You can also do that in C++ with the right tools. Qt being one of them. He asked about C++, why bring C# ???

Comment: @anno: Because I'm commenting, not answering. Because C# and C++ are extremely similar and learning it is trivial. Because his fears may be unfounded. Because you can still write C++ code while using C# and WinForms/WPF. Because he asked about MFC which is still Windows-specific, so he's not concerned with platform-independence.

Answer (score 9):

Go with Qt if you envision porting your program to platforms other than Windows and/or your actual UI needs are relatively straightforward.  But Qt, being "fun," abstracts you away from the Windows API, so if you find yourself needing to access features of that API not offered by Qt, then you'll be up the creek.  So go with MFC if you're staying on Windows and you're building an application whose complexity or Windows-specific features may require more direct access to the Windows API.  MFC provides a thin abstraction layer over that API; its concepts map more or less one-to-one with the API's concepts.

Comment: You can alyaws access the Win32 API in Qt.

Answer (score 5):

What kind of GUI do you want?  Any framework should be able to do any kind of GUI, but some are optimized for certain work:

- MFC is optimized for making applications that edit documents, like MS Office programs Word, Excel, Powerpoint.
- wxWidgets and Qt (and .NET WinForms and WPF) are optimized for any sort of app that primarily uses widgets (textboxes, buttons, menus).
- SDL is optimized if you want to draw stuff, like graphs or vector artwork.

I wouldn't recommend that you use MFC since it isn't a good fit for most applications, and also doesn't use modern C++ design, it's loaded with workarounds needed for stuff that was broken in early versions of Visual C++ and now can't shake those workarounds because of backward compatibility.

The Win32 API is actually really useful to know regardless of what kind of application you want to make, because it defines the rules for how the UI interfaces to the rest of the system.  Yes, it's written in C, but this is to make it usable from any programming language, not because it's an obsolete design.  Win32 API is highly object-oriented and uses polymorphism extensively.

Answer (score 2):

Few things you need to be aware of:

If one day you want to sell a program written using Qt you might need to purchase a license.

If you feel like GUI applications/ GUI programming is what you want to do in general, for windows platform you better learn WinForms or even better WPF (with C# of course).

If you just want to quickly put up simple GUIs for your C++ programs for learning purposes, and you don't care much about learning the frameworks and licensing issues, just go with Qt or wxWidgets.

Comment: @anno I am aware of that. Thats why it doesn't say "you will have to purchase" but "you most likely need to purchase." Since it looks like I hurt some Qt fans feelings I'll edit it to "you might need..."

Comment: downvote: Because, he asked about C++ and even explicitely excluded C#

Comment: I disagree with the downvote. He did not "explicitely" exclude C#, he mentioned that he's not interested in learning C# because he's concerned that doing so would be unwise while still learning C#. Addressing his concern is not irrelevant, invalid, or inappropriate in any way. All the same, he also commented about Qt and the possibility of needing a license, which is an important piece of information in selecting any third-party code.

Answer (score 0):

MFC is outdated. If sticking with C++ on Windows, I recommend you to lean C++ CLI. 
However I suggest you to learn c# directly since c# is the mainstream language in .Net world. 
For GUI, the windows world is now dominated by WPF.

Comment: ".. dominated by WPF": which applications use WPF - except those from Microsoft?

Comment: Only Microsoft use WPF? For a simple example, Yahoo messenger makes use of WPF, there are tons of others.